# how to increase resolution of map in yaml file

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, yaml, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using `rtabmap` to get map of environment. For saving 2D projection of map I type:

```
rosrun map_server map_saver -f map
```

As a result I get a `yaml` file with a resolution is equal to 0.05. Is there a way to increase this resolution?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382354/how-to-increase-resolution-of-map-in-yaml-file/) by [Ivan4815162342](https://answers.ros.org/users/53129/ivan4815162342/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a parameter `Grid/CellSize` whose value can be modified from the default 0.05 ([source code](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/blob/master/corelib/include/rtabmap/core/Parameters.h#L734)).

As stated in the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/#rtabmap), call the node `rtabmap` with `--params` to show all available parameters.

---

Originally posted by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) with karma: 228 on 2021-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan4815162342](https://answers.ros.org/users/53129/ivan4815162342/) on 2021-07-14**:
I tried to launch `rtabmap` with `Grid/CellSize` parameter is equal to 0.05 and 0.5 but the resolution in the `yaml` file was the same for both cases.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2021-07-30**:
The parameter may not be correctly set:

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap" args:="--delete_db_on_start --Grid/CellSize 0.1">
...
</node>
```

or

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap" args:="--delete_db_on_start">
   <param name="Grid/CellSize" value="0.1"/>
</node>
```